# Toonami anime about a boy with a sword and a girl with weird Uzis

Tags: story-identification, anime, toonami

This anime was shown in the earlier 2000's on Toonami.

I remember a boy with a sword who had to go on a journey around the world. He met a girl with brown hair, but he was reluctant to help in the beginning.

The girl had two guns that she called Uzis (I think), but they were shaped like this and were red and white:

[image: A police baton—about 3/4 along the length of the main rod is another part 1/4 as long as the baton sticking out at a 90-degree angle]

I remember one episode where the girl had to get her guns fixed, or something, but the shop owner actually made them too powerful and they had a huge recoil when she shot.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11874/101407) for asking anime questions, in case there's anything else there you forgot to add.

Comment: "Boy with a sword" implies this is a fantasy setting, but is there anything *definitely* fantastical about it that you can remember? Perhaps the guns were magical in some way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is *[Rave Master](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rave_Master)*, which began its run on Toonami June 5th, 2004.

> The main character Haru Glory, is chosen by the holy artifact known as Rave to wield the Ten Powers and go on a quest with the strange dog like creature known as Plue to find the other four remaining Rave stones and put an end to the usage of Dark Bring and bring peace to the world. In his travel, fate brings him to ally himself with a girl that lost her memories and believes she is named Elie and is unaware that she has a strong involvement with the Rave stones. Together on their quest, they gain allies known as the Rave Warriors which consist of the thief that can manipulate silver known as Hamrio Musica, a cartographer which is the strange blue creature known as Griffon Kato, Let Dahaka and Julia who are both martial artists and members of a species from the mystic realm known as the Dragon Race, Ruby, a rich penguin-like sentenoid, and Belnika, a kind sorceress.

The boy is [Haru Glory](https://ravemaster.fandom.com/wiki/Haru_Glory) and the girl is Elie and her [Tonfa Blasters](https://ravemaster.fandom.com/wiki/Tonfa_Blasters).

> Her M-644 model are red and black in color, and can shoot multiple rounds of bullets, much like a machine gun. This feature is especially useful when Elie goes on a rampage and tries to shoot everything. The blasters are held using a handle that lays towards the side of the blasters so that the blasters lay across the user’s arms. As a result, they still function as regular tonfas for close combat and self-defense, such as Elie blocking attacks from Rosa’s blade.
>
> During the Lance arc, they were mistakenly modified to fire stronger rounds with less ammo. When Elie first learns to use magic, she applies Etherion to her tonfas during her fight with Koala, replacing her ammo to fire magic bullets.

[image: Elie firing her Tonfa Blasters]

### Opening

I found this with a search for *anime girl tonfa guns red and white*. Good work on details provided.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. This is exactly right :)